# how ... if statement and button content "WP7"

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

What is the right way to do this? This way is not working:

```
if (((String)enterAmountButton.Content) == "")
 MessageBox.Show("Please enter the total bill amount.");
else if (((String)enterTipButton.Content) == "")
 MessageBox.Show("Please enter the tip % amount.");
```

this way is not working neither:

```
if (enterAmountButton.Content == "")   
 MessageBox.Show("Please enter the total bill amount.");   
else if (enterTipButton.Content == "")   
 MessageBox.Show("Please enter the tip % amount.");
```

Comment: Please try to debug before posting..I believe you can see the type of Content and cast to string appropriately.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
var amountButtonString = enterAmountButton.Content as string;
        var enterTipButtonString = enterTipButton.Content as string;
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(amountButtonString))
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter the total bill amount.");
        else if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(enterTipButtonString))
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter the tip % amount.");
```

would work. However, how are you expecting to get the strings? you most likely want the value in a TextBox that is next to the button, correct?

in that case:

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(amountTextBox.Text))
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter the total bill amount.");
            else if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(tipTextBox.Text))
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter the tip % amount.");
```

where `amountTextBox` & `tipTextBox`  are the `x:Name` of your `TextBoxes`.

One last thing:

There's probably a better way to handle this. For example, if you handle the KeyUp & TextChanged events on the TextBoxes and only Enable the button when text exists (even better, valid text ;))

You could use a converter too:

```
public class StringToEnabledConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        #region IValueConverter Members

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var val = value as string;
            if (val == null)
                throw new ArgumentException("value must be a string.");

            return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(val);
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

Add a reference to your converter `<Converters:StringToEnabledConverter x:Key="StringToEnabledConverter" />`

and on your button,

```
<TextBox x:Name="amountTextBox />
<Button x:Name="enterAmountButton" Enabled="{Binding ElementName=amountTextBox, Path=Text, Converter={StaticResource StringToEnabledConverter}}" />
```

Comment: What im doing with the button is. When the page load, the button text is empty. When the user click on the button, the user is directed to a second page, where he input some numbers. When he return to the previous page, those numbers get display in the button text. I just want to user to made sure to input data to each text and if he don't, I want to display a message telling him to input data to the button the that have no text.

Comment: @Twenty40 well than what's wrong with the first segment of code?

Answer (score 0):

```
if ((string)(enterAmountButton.Content) == "")   
 MessageBox.Show("Please enter the total bill amount.");   
else if ((string)(enterTipButton.Content) == "")   
 MessageBox.Show("Please enter the tip % amount.");
```

or alternatively

```
if (enterAmountButton.Content.ToString() == "")   
 MessageBox.Show("Please enter the total bill amount.");   
else if (enterTipButton.Content.ToString() == "")   
 MessageBox.Show("Please enter the tip % amount.");
```

Comment: The first solution assumes that Content can be cast to a string.  If it cannot, you need to use `ToString()`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
if(enterAmountButton.Content.ToString().Trim() == String.Empty)   
 MessageBox.Show("Please enter the total bill amount.");   
else if (enterTipButton.Content.ToString().Trim() == String.Empty)   
 MessageBox.Show("Please enter the tip % amount.");
```

The `Trim()` ensures that there aren't any leading or trailing blank spaces. Maybe that's why your first try wasn't working?

Comment: Instead of String.Empty . we can use string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(enterAmountButton.Content.ToString().Trim())